# MVC и заголовок

Tags: php, mvc, framework

Доброго времени суток. Решил разобраться с MVC и тому подобному. Нашёл простую и понятную статью на хабре - [Реализация MVC паттерна на примере создания сайта-визитки на PHP](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150267/). Однако возник вопрос, связанный с шаблонами.

Имеется стандартный шаблон `template_view.php`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Главная</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Описание">    
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'application/views/'.$content_view; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Когда пользователь переходит на какую-либо страницу сайта основной каркас страницы берётся именно из этого шаблона. А "начинка" - из других views, как прописано в `controller_main.php`

```
class Controller_Main extends Controller
{
    function action_index()
    {   
        $this->view->generate('main_view.php', 'template_view.php');
    }
}
```

Однако `template_view.php` включает в себя и некоторые не статичные элементы - title, description и многое другое. Я понимаю, что можно передать в этот шаблон данные, которые будут подставлены в title и description. Однако:

1. Откуда мне брать эти данные? Они должны храниться в БД в отдельной таблице, например, `pages`? И данные из БД я буду вытаскивать с помощью специальной модели? Или нежен какой-то отдельный файл с классами и т.п., которые будут хранить всю эту информацию в виде массивов и выдавать нужное? Или ещё как-то?
2. Когда я подключаю контроллер, то `generate('main_view.php', 'template_view.php')` генерирую страницу на основе `template_view.php` с подстановкой в указанное место данных из файла `main_view.php`. Если я буду передавать туда ещё и заголовки и т.п., то они будут обработаны в шаблоне? Т.е. мы открываем `main_view.php`, заменяем там все метки данными (если бы мы их передавали) и уже готовый оформленный html вставляем в 'main_view.php'. Но тогда как что-то вставить в `template_view.php`?

Comment: `$this->view->setTitle("Title"); $this->view->setDescription("Description"); $this->view->generate(...)` ? А где хранить неважно, если нет необходимости менять пользователем, можно прям в контроллере.

Comment: Опять в вашем примере передаёться дата `function generate($content_view, $template_view, $data = null)` что мешает сразу так и передать?

Comment: @E_p у меня нет отдельных фукций setTitle() и setDescription() в классе View. Но я могу передать данные как вы написали во втором комментарии. Вопрос тут в том, что если <title> Изначально находится в базовом шаблоне, то сработает ли замена (мой второй вопрос)?

Comment: Если код такой как в статье то 100% сработает.

Comment: @E_p Скажите, если получать данные о странице из массива прямо в контроллере, то на каком этапе и в каком именно контроллере? Могу предположить, что сразу в `route.php` (`class Rout` `function start()`), где осуществляется роутинг и т.п. Или где и как?

Comment: Не уверен зачем их в массив отдельно выносить? Только путаницу делать, ведь будет трудно понять где что используеться. Ну если очень хочеться, есть варианты. Контроллер от которого наследуют, не особо хорошо но централизированно. Можно добавить какой DI контейнет типа Pimple(или свой) тянуть другим классом и передовать внутрь как зависимость.  Т.е. всё зависит от требований и как тренировка, не вижу смысла усложнять без причины.

Comment: @E_p хорошо, давайте иначе вопрос поставим - как будет правильно? Если сайт - несколько простых страниц? Я себе представляю так: массив виде array('вызываемая страница' => array('title'=>'заголовок', 'description'=>'Описание'). И так для каждой страницы. А т.к. мы получаем вызываемую страницу и др в файле `route.php`, то зачем делать ту же работу повторно таким же кодом в другом месте? Значит это нужно решать там, нет? Как тут быть? Я просто хочу самым простым и верным способом вывести `title` и `description`.

Comment: `route.php` - по названию только перенаправляет запрос, он не должен знать про titles, headers, templates,как вы этот запрос обрабатываете...  Если есть действия которые надо делать в каждом контроллере, но повторять код не хочется то его выносят в middleware. Я считаю, если задача просто сайт визитка, то лучше взять любой статический сайт-генератор. Если думаете добавлять функционал `server side` то тут много вариантов. Помните вы берете "академический" материал смысл которого научить. Контроллером может выступать даже простая функция.

Comment: @E_p спасибо, понимаю. Создал функцию `get_page_info()`  в `controller.php`, которая возвращает массив с `title` и др. Ну и получая эти данные в каждом отдельном контроллере страницы.